# What are the execution sequence of ready,load and focus events among various browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

What are the execution sequence of following events among various browsers(It seems browser events execute in different sequence)-

1. document.ready
2. document.load
3. document.focus

also is there any event exists which gets called after focus event where we could set some flag and we can put some logic on that flag so that focus event handler could not get called first time but it should get called in subsequent focus.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Ready is when the DOM is ready. In that, you may start using `document.getElementById()`. Load is when all frames and images are done loading. As for `is there [..] focus event handler [..] not get called first time but it should get called in [next] focus`, yeah I believe you answered your own question. Set a flag (boolean), and then run code for subsequent focuses.

Comment: @DaveChen-yeah I also believed the same for focus event but in fire fox focus event gets called first time only although your opinion holds correct for chrome , IE. Is there any way to manage the focus event in Firefox  also similar to other browsers?below is my code-<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function alerting(){
   if (checkVar == true) {
                    alert("focus function is called");
                }}   
 var checkVar = false
        $(document).ready(function () { 
          $(document).on('focus',alerting);
          checkVar = true; );</script>

Comment: I might try that test using console.log instead of alert just to see if the alert holds things up.